# In Perl, can you use a variable for the whole of a match string?

Tags: perl

I'm new to Perl, though not to programming, and am working through [Learning Perl](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920049517.do). The book has exercises to match successive lines of a small text file.

I had the idea of supplying match strings from `STDIN`, and going through the file for each one:

```
while(<STDIN>) {
    chomp;
    $regex = $_;
    seek JUNK, 0, 0;
    while(<JUNK>) {
        chomp();
        if(/$regex/) {
            say;
        }
    }
    say '';
}
```

This works fine, but I can't find a way to interpolate an entire match string, e.g.

```
/fred/i
```

into the predicate.  I tried

```
if($$matcher) # with $matcher = '/fred/'
```

but Perl complained.

I imagine this is my ignorance, and should welcome enlightenment.

Comment: Try `(?i:fred)`, see [Extended patterns](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Extended-Patterns) in `perldoc perlre` for more information

Comment: One other minor improvement: use `$regex = qr/$_/` to [compile the pattern once](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators) instead of every time `/$regex/` is evaluated.

Comment: (1) Use `strict` and `warnings`,. Always, and certainly while playing! (2) Use lexical filehandles

Comment: @zdim if they work through Learning Perl they'll have strict and warnings, and possibly even more pragmas. If it's the newest edition, they'll probably have `use v5.12` I think. I don't have that edition,but their code has `say`.

Comment: Would you mind quoting the relevant part of the task from the book, and tell us which edition? The chapter organisation has changed at some point iirc.

Comment: @simbabque  I haven't seen that book since way back then .. but that `$regex` should be declared right there (and with `qr`, but OK on that). Perhaps they dropped it to make things simpler? Only prudent to mention it, I thought. There are typeglobs? The `chomp` has-or-not an extra `()`. I'd hope that the book provides the framework, but some things itch here.  I do like their idea.

Comment: Håkon, thanks so much, exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @HåkonHægland: Please would you write up your comment as an answer so that the OP can accept it. At present the accepted "solution" is not a solution at all.

Comment: *"but Perl complained"* This is no better than "didn't work" as a description of the problem. Please always be specific with your descriptions of errors. It will help us to find a solution for you, and more importantly will aid those who are searching for an answer to a similar problem.

Comment: @Borodin But it really was a complete solution.  'Didn't work' would be obvious to anyone with Perl experience, and Håkon fixed it fo me.

Comment: @Borodin Added my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Problem

What you are trying to do can be summarized by:

```
my $regex = '/fred/i';
my @lines = (
    'A line containing some words and Fred said Hello.',
    'Another line. Here is a regex embedded in the line: /fred/i',
);

for ( @lines ) {
    say if /$regex/;
}
```

**Output**:

```
Another line. Here is a regex embedded in the line: /fred/i
```

We see that the second line matches `$regex`, whereas we wanted the first line containing `Fred` to match the string `fred` with the (case insensitive) `i` flag added to the regex. The problem is that the characters `/` and `i` in `$regex` are taken as characters to be matched literally, i.e., they are not interpreted as special characters surrounding a Regex (as part of a Perl expression).

**Note**:

The character `/` is special as part of a Perl expression for a regular expression, but it is not special *inside* the Regex pattern. There are however characters that are special inside the pattern, the so-called meta characters:

```
\ | ( ) [ { ^ $ * + ? .
```

see [`perldoc quotemeta`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html) for more information.

## A solution using extended patterns

Simply change the first line to:

```
my $regex = '(?i)fred';  # or alternatively: (?i:fred)
```

Regex flags can be added to a regex pattern using *"Extended patterns"*  described in the manual [`perldoc perlre`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Extended-Patterns) :

> Extended Patterns
>
> The syntax for most of these is a pair of parentheses with a question
>   mark as the first thing within the parentheses. The character after
>   the question mark indicates the extension.
>
> [...]
>
> **(?adlupimnsx-imnsx)**
>   **(?^alupimnsx)**
>   One or more embedded pattern-match modifiers, to be turned on (or
>   turned off if preceded by "-" ) for the remainder of the pattern or
>   the remainder of the enclosing pattern group (if any). *This is
>   particularly useful for dynamically-generated patterns*, such as those
>   read in from a configuration file, taken from an argument, or
>   specified in a table somewhere.
>
> [...]
>
> These modifiers are restored at the end of the enclosing group.

Alternatively the non-capturing form can be used:

> **(?:pattern)**
>   **(?adluimnsx-imnsx:pattern)**
>   **(?^aluimnsx:pattern)**
>   This is for clustering, not capturing; it groups subexpressions like
>   "()"  , but doesn't make backreferences as "()" does.

Answer (score 3):

Statement modifiers, such as `/i`, are a part of the code telling Perl how to perform the match, not a part of the pattern to be matched.  This is why that doesn't work for you.

You have three ways to work around this (well, probably more, since this is Perl we're talking about, but three ways that I can think of straight off):

1) Use extended regex syntax and, when you want a case-insensitive match, enter `(?i:fred)`, as suggested in comments on the question.

2) Use string `eval` to allow the use of the regular statement modifiers: `if (eval "$_ =~ $regex") { say }`  Note that this method will require you to also type the surrounding slashes.  e.g., You'd have to enter `/fred/i`; just typing in `fred` would not work.  Note also that it's a *huge* security hole to do this without validating your input first, since the user's entered text is executed as Perl code, just as if it were part of the original program.  (Imagine if the user entered `//, system("rm -rf /")` - it would test against an empty regex, then delete all the files on your computer.)  So probably not a recommended approach unless you really know what you're doing and/or you're the only one who will ever run the program.

3) The most complex, but also most correct, solution is to write a parser which inspects the user's entered string to see whether any special flags are present and then responds accordingly.  A very simple example which allows the user to append `/i` for a case-insensitive search:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl    

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

while(<STDIN>) {
  chomp;
  my @parts = split '/', $_;

  # If the user input starts with a /, the first part will be empty, so throw
  # it away.
  shift @parts unless $parts[0];

  my $re = shift @parts;
  my %flags;
  for (@parts) {
    for (split '') {
      $flags{i} = 1 if $_ eq 'i';
    }
  }
  my $f = join '', keys %flags;
  say "Matched" if eval qq('foo' =~ /$re/$f);
}
```

This also uses string `eval`, so it is potentially vulnerable to the same kind of security issues as #2, but `$re` cannot contain any `/` characters (the `split '/'` would have ended `$re` immediately prior to the first `/`), which prevents code from being inserted there and `$f` can contain only the letter `i` (or any other flags you might choose to recognize if you expand on this).  So it *should* be safe.  (But, if anyone can demonstrate an exploit I missed, please tell me about it in comments!)

Comment: Thanks Dave.  Security is not an issue here, it's just me trying to minimise the time spent on the exercises.  'I' and 'the user' are one:-). As you say, Hakon provided the answer in the first comment.  But i've learnt such a lot from your answer.

Comment: @JohnWhite While all of Dave's suggestions are correct, I think none of them is the intended solution, becaue they are all too advanced for the Learning Perl book. I think you misunderstand your task are over-complicating. Take a step back and reread the assignment. It should be solvable from only the things you've done in the previous chapters and up to where the task is.

Comment: @simbabque  I think that JohnWhite came up with the `STDIN` loop on his own and that that is not a part of the assignment (to test the matching). And I now think that their desire is to be able to type in the pattern and flags. So it turned out it needs more advanced techniques.  It's a shame that we have to guess so much though.

Comment: @zdim yes, I agree. He should tell us that part, thus my request for clarification. I don't have my editions of LP with me (I think I have at least two different ones, one in German) so I can't check.

Comment: Håkon, thanks so much, exactly what I was looking for.  Can I credit you with the answer?

Others: I didn't mean to suggest that any of the code quoted came from the book.  It's all my own code, written as a simple convenience for doing the exercises in Chapter 7, page 131, 6th edition. And yes,I have put strict, utf8 etc. at the top of all my testing code, as advised by the authors.

zdim:  The point is, a match string is not necessarily just a regex.  The regex may have e..g. an 'i' after its terminator.

Comment: Damn, I wish I hadn't mentioned the book:-)...   I

t is absolutely true that you can answer the questions without all the stuff I offered.  But, as an experienced programmer, I am naturally lazy, and find it convenient just to type in the various match strings, and see the results without more ado or thought.

I have skimmed a lot of the stuff, but have been heavily engaged by CONTEXT and REGEXP, and, I guess, more to come.  (I've got the 'Camel Book' as well, but couldn't find what I needed, until now

Thanks to all, especially Hakon, and sorry, @zim, for misleading you.

Comment: @simbabque I just noticed you said 'use 5.12' was suggested if you wanted to use 'say'.  The book does say 'use 5.10', but these days it seems better to say 'use feature say'...

And, I haven't misunderstood my task, which is to get to grips with the Mighty Perl as conveniently as I can, leveraging my experience.

Comment: @simbabque The initial text of the question states "I had the idea of supplying match strings from STDIN". To me, at least, this made it quite clear that reading the pattern and flags from `STDIN` was his own elaboration on the exercise, not a part of the assignment as presented by the book.

Comment: @Dave, I noticed you said "Statement modifiers, such as /i, are a part of the code telling Perl how to perform the match, not a part of the pattern to be matched".... ..Could you tell me the correct term for the sequence '/fred/i', which is the thing I want to read in and apply to the target line.

Comment: @JohnWhite Thanks for clarifications. The `/fred/i` is ... well, a regular expression. I don't know that there'd be a special term to signify that it (match operator with the pattern) has some modifiers on it.  (But when you read that via `STDIN`, or from a file etc, then it's just a dummy string of chars, as you found out.)

Answer (score -1):

The question has been answered in the following comment:

> Try `(?i:fred)`, see [Extended
>   patterns](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Extended-Patterns) in
>   `perldoc perlre` for more information

– [Håkon Hægland 7 hours ago.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45230211/in-perl-can-you-use-a-variable-for-the-whole-of-a-match-string#comment77426748_45230211)

Comment: @Dave Sherohman's answer was *very* interesting, but the response from Håkon was more immediately helpful...