# Perl filter with substitution

Tags: perl

I am attempting to create a Perl script that filters data presented on STDIN, changing all occurrences of
one string to another and outputting all input lines, changed and unchanged to STDOUT. FROMSTRING and TOSTRING can be PERL-compatible regular expressions. I am unable to get matching output.

Here is an example of what I am trying to achieve.

```
echo "Today is Saturday" | f.pl 'a' '@'
```

Output `Tod@y is S@turd@y`.

```
echo io | filter.pl '([aeiou])([aeiou])' '$2$1'
```

Output `oi`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
if (@ARGV != 2){
        print STDERR "Usage: ./filter.pl FROMSTRING TOSTRING\n"
}
exit 1;
my $FROM = $ARGV[0];
my $TO = $ARGV[1];
my $inLine = "";
while (<STDIN>){
$inLine = $_;
$inLine =~ s/$FROM/$TO/;
print  $inLine
}
exit 0;
```

Comment: Note -- can do `while (my $inline = <STDIN>) { ... }`. Also, `my ($from, $to) = @ARGV;`

Comment: Or `print s/$from/$to/r  while <STDIN>;` with `/r` modifier [from 5.14](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl5140delta.html)

Answer (score 6):

First off, the replacement part of a `s/.../.../` operation is not a regex; it works like a double-quoted string.

There are a couple of issues with your code.

- Your `exit 1;` statement appears in the middle of the main code, not in the error block. You probably want:

  ```
  if (@ARGV != 2) {
      print STDERR "Usage: ./filter.pl FROMSTRING TOSTRING\n";
      exit 1;
  }
  ```
- You're missing a `g` flag if you want multiple substitutions to happen in the same line:

  ```
  $inLine =~ s/$FROM/$TO/g;
  ```
- There's no need to predeclare `$inLine`; it's only used in one block.
- There's also no need to read a line into `$_` just to copy it into `$inLine`.
- It's common to use `$names_like_this` for variables and functions, not `$namesLikeThis`.
- You can use `$0` instead of hardcoding the program name in the error message.
- `exit 0;` is redundant at the end.

The following is closer to how I'd write it:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

if (@ARGV != 2) {
    die "Usage: $0 FROMSTRING TOSTRING\n";
}

my ($from, $to) = @ARGV;

while (my $line = readline STDIN) {
    $line =~ s/$from/$to/g;
    print $line;
}
```

---

That said, none of this addresses your second example with `'$2$1'` as the replacement. The above code won't do what you want because `$to` is a plain string. Perl won't scan it to look for things like `$1` and replace them.

When you write `"foo $bar baz"` in your code, it means the same thing as `'foo ' . $bar . ' baz'`, but this only applies to code, i.e. stuff that literally appears in your source code. The contents of `$bar` aren't re-scanned at runtime to expand e.g. `\n` or `$quux`. This also applies to `$1` and friends, which are just normal variables.

So how do you get `'$2$1'` to work?

One way is to mess around with `eval`, but I don't like it because, well, it's `eval`: If you're not very careful, it would allow someone to execute arbitrary code by passing the right replacement "string".

Doing it without `eval` is possible and even easy with e.g. [`Data::Munge::replace`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Munge#replace-STRING,-REGEX,-REPLACEMENT,-FLAG):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Munge qw(replace);

if (@ARGV != 2) {
    die "Usage: $0 FROMSTRING TOSTRING\n";
}

my ($from, $to) = @ARGV;

while (my $line = readline STDIN) {
    print replace($line, $from, $to, 'g');
}
```

`replace` works like JavaScript's [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) in that it expands special `$` sequences.

Doing it by hand is also possible but slightly annoying because you basically have to treat `$to` as a template and expand all `$` sequences by hand (e.g. by using another regex substitution):

```
# untested
$line =~ s{$from}{
    my @start = @-;
    my @stop  = @+;
    (my $r = $to) =~ s{\$([0-9]+|\$)}{
        $1 eq '$'
            ? '$'
            : substr($from, $start[$1], $stop[$1] - $start[$1])
    }eg;
    $r
}eg;
```

(This does not implement braced groups such as `${1}`, `${2}`, etc. Those are left as an exercise for the reader.)

This code is sufficiently annoying to write (and look at) that I much prefer using a module like [`Data::Munge`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Munge) for this sort of thing.

Comment: Good to mention that module.  Perhaps a skinny comment on using `readline` instead of its operator form `<>`?  I figure you prefer it for readability and canonical meaning in computing (and I don't complain!), but it may confuse a beginner (as in why-this-and-not-that) ?

Comment: I never use `<` `>` because of its ad-hoc syntactic overloading: `<$foo>` means `readline($foo)` but `<${foo}>` and `<$ foo>` mean `glob($foo)`. It's much clearer (and unambiguous) to just write out `readline` and `glob` in all cases. (Bonus: Non-Perl programmers understand what's going on.)

Comment: I thought so and I completely agree with the argument.  I was referring to the answer, as aimed at a beginner.  But then this does much more than a short comment (which isn't necessary either).

Comment: I must say, while I agree with all you say, `<$fh>` _is_ one of the most standard idioms in Perl.

Comment: @melpomene Thank you for the information. I was doing some research on my own and was trying to implement eval qq("$ARGV[1]") but was unsuccessful. Would you mind briefly explaining it also?

Comment: @user8351474 I'm not sure what exactly you're asking here but I don't want to think about `eval`. It's yucky.

Comment: [String::Substitution](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?String::Substitution) is another module that does this. It has a variety of related functions instead of the single Data::Munge provides. Data::Munge appears to pick random individual functions from a variety of modules???

Comment: @ikegami I didn't know about `String::Substitution` but it seems to have some subtle traps: `last_match_vars` is described as returning a list of `($1, $2, ...)` from the last match. After e.g. `"abc" =~ /(a)(x)?(.)|(foo) (bar)/` perl sets `$1 = 'a'`, `$2 = undef`, `$3 = 'b'`, `$4 = undef`, `$5 = undef`, so you'd expect `last_match_vars` to return `(undef, 'a', undef, 'b', undef, undef)`. What it actually returns is `(undef, 'a', '', 'b')`, i.e. it returns too few values and one of the `undef`s has become an empty string. `interpolate_match_vars` has subtle bugs with Unicode digits.

Comment: @ikegami ... whereas `Data::Munge::submatches` returns `('a', undef, 'b', undef, undef)` - nice and simple (and no leading `undef`). `Data::Munge::replace` also supports `$&`, `$\``, `$'` with no performance penalty.

Answer (score 0):

three errors found:

```
; after error message
exit 1;
$inLine =~ s/$FROM/$TO/g;
```

like:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
if (@ARGV != 2){
        print STDERR "Usage: ./filter.pl FROMSTRING TOSTRING\n";
        exit 1;
}
my $FROM = $ARGV[0];
my $TO = $ARGV[1];
my $inLine = "";
while (<STDIN>){
$inLine = $_;
$inLine =~ s/$FROM/$TO/g;
print  $inLine
}
exit 0;
```

Comment: Thank you, those were just simple syntax errors that I overlooked. However when I try something more complex like filter.pl '([aeiou])([aeiou])' '$2$1'` It is not completing correctly.

Comment: You don't need a `;` after the last statement in a block.

Comment: @user8351474  The `'$2$1'` is a literal string (just those four characters) and that's how it's treated in the regex.  So you'll get the result of `$2$1`.  So you need to endow that input string with its meaning in the regex (in this case, variables `$2` and `$1`), what isn't simple. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45233407/4653379) for the same kind of a problem.